# Calculate BMI Average for arrays within for loop for file

Tags: c

I want to find the average of the bmi based on all the data within the variables height and weight.
I don't understand how to compute an average or what expression to put for mbmi

```
input:
int M; // Variable for man
int mbmi; / Variable for bmi
int i =0;
while(fscanf(covid, "%c %d %d %d %c %d", &sex, &age, &height, &weight, &sign, &code) != EOF){
i++
}
for(int i = 0; i< 750; i++)
{
   if(sex[i] == 'M')
{
  M++;
  if(sign[i] == '+'){
   mbmi = height[i] /(weight[i]*weight[i]);
   }

}

output:
printf("\nAverage BMI of males who tested positive: %f ", mbmi)
```

Comment: You appear to be reading into single variables and then trying to treat them as an array. Please work on a [mcve] that includes all of the relevant code and any errors you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your BMI calculation is flipped the wrong way. It should be the weight divided by the height squared, not the height divided by the weight squared. See https://www.cdc.gov/nccdphp/dnpao/growthcharts/training/bmiage/page5_1.html.

Secondly, you'll want to be computing two separate things - (1) the BMI for a particular individual and (2) the average of the BMIs. Your current output at the end would print the BMI of the last person in the data, rather than the average. You will need to introduce some more variables.

Remember that the average of a dataset (in this case the average BMI) is just the sum of the data points divided by the number of data points. So, to compute the average BMI, you should sum up the BMIs first and then at the end, divide by how many there were (in this case just the BMIs of positive males).

Lastly, your code shouldn't need a `while` loop and a `for` loop. You would only need to read each set of numbers in once, process them and then move onto the next line of input. So, in that case, you could remove the `for` loop and just rely on the `while` loop for the input. The body of the `while` loop would then check for positive males, compute their BMI, and add it to a running total. This also means you wouldn't need to store any of the weight, height, etc values in an array, so you can remove any reference to the `i` variable, and any array indexing.

Comment: So let's say I make a new variable which is double bmi                      bmi=weight[i]/(height[i]*height[i]);  mbmi = mbmi + bmi; Would  that be suffienct?

Comment: Looks good! So then `mbmi` would track the total sum of the BMIs.